# The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am Getting the following error when I run my Unit Test  (The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created)

Inside my context constructor I have set the

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

In my Unit test I am mocking the context. I have also added this code to the unit test and it still fails. Is there anything else that needs to be done apart from the `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`

My Context is here

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
  {
    public MyContext () : base("MyContext") 
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    }
  }
```

My Mock in the unit test

```
  var _context = new Mock<MyContext>();
  Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
  _classUnderTest = new Repo(_context.Object);
```

I get the error here

```
  _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Comment: Your Mock model does not reflect the state of the database. Check whether Mock actually exactly matches the real DB model.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understood the question but If you are using Entity framework Code First approach, After model change, Try Enabling the migrations in your application. It can be done using the package manager console..

Refer this link for more details.[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx)

Comment: Hi I dont want Migrations thats why I am setting Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null); But I am still getting the migrations error

Answer (score 0):

Turns Out that EF under the hood if no connection string is provided will default a connection to sql express. So the way to solve this is not to Mock the Context but extract a interface from the context and mock that. Turns out the example on MSDN is pretty poor as they mock the actual context and not an abstraction.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396